# How to interpret independent dummy variables in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, binary-data, categorical-encoding

I have both quantitative and dummy independent variables in my logistic regression. Dependent variable is binary. I have 2 questions.

1. How to interpret a quantitative variable that is negative?
2. How to interpret dummy variable with more than 2 categories? I have n-1 variables, so there is a base category to compare each dummy variable against.

Comment: How would you do it in a linear regression?

Comment: @Daveis it the same for logistic regression as well? From what I know, we dont interpret the coefficient but rather its sign (+ or-) in logistic regression. So, how do we compare against base category? If the sign of the dummy variable is (-), do I assume the opposite for the base category?

Comment: Many similar Qs on site:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213362/logistic-regression-categorical-variable-interpretation-after-transformed-into-d,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272574/logistic-regression-coefficient-interpretation-for-more-than-2-dummy-variables